# Does the torque due to gravity on an object in free fall produce angular acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, projectile, rotation

A question in my textbook (*Concepts of Physics, Part 1,* by HC Verma), reads:

> A heavy particle of mass m falls freely near the earth's surface. What is the torque acting on this particle about a point 50 cm east to the line of motion? Does this torque produce any angular acceleration in the particle?

Suppose the distance is *r*, not 50cm, clearly the torque applied by gravity in such a case is:

$τ=mgr$

However, does the torque produce angular acceleration if the object is moving in a straight line? I think it does but some other websites I have consulted disagree. A common response is that since the object is moving in a straight line, $r=∞$, $I=∞$ and thus $α=0$. However, I don't quite understand how $r=∞$, since the question pretty clearly specifies the axis of rotation.

Comment: Why do you think there is no angular acceleration? If it starts from rest, the particle's    angle seen  from P wrt horizontal  is given by $\theta = \tan^{-1}[(at^2)/r]$  and that is changing in a non-linear way.

Comment: @Mikestone so you're saying that moving in a straight line does not necessarily debar it from being in rotational motion about an axis?

Comment: You don't need an axis or rotation to have a changing angle  You just need to write $\dot {\bf r}= {\boldsymbol \omega}\times {\bf r}$ to define the instantaneous angular velcity..

Comment: @Mikestone so $I$ in this case is just $mr^2$?

Comment: Moments of inertia are not very useful when they are time dependent, but you still have torque = time rate of change of angular momentum when you take moments about a fixed point like your P. Your $I$ formula holds at the instant that ${\bf r} \cdot \dot {\bf r}=0$ though

Comment: @mikestone some other sites I've referenced say that since the object is moving in a straight line, $r=∞$ and thus $I=∞$, making $α=0$. Also, how is the Moment of Inertia time dependent if r is constant?

Comment: You have defined $r$ as  the distance of the moving particle  from your P and it is therefore changing with time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143022/discussion-between-callouscalculus-and-mike-stone).